# Removing HTML tags from a string of text

Tags: c++

For a bit of a practice assignment, my professor challenged the lecture to write up some code that removes HTML tags from a string of text. He mentioned a specific command that we would learn later on that would do this for us, but he wants us to do so manually.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name = "<HTML> smelly </b> butts </b> smell<test>";
  cout << name << endl;

  int a = 0, b = 0;

  for (int a = b; a < name.length(); a++) {
      if (name[a] == '<') {
          for (int b = a; b < name.length(); b++) {
              if (name[b] == '>') {
                  name.erase(a, (b + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  cout << name << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but I'm not getting the correct output.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Think about what happens when you make your first erase. Is the string still the same length? Is your position in the string still valid? Try doing the same logic, in reverse.

Comment: Do you want to remove just <HTML> tags or all tags with < >? Because your code removes the removes the first <HTML> tag.

Comment: There are some Tree which hold all the tags. then it would be easy to remove anything. you can search by HTML parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int b = a; b < name.length(); b++) {
    if (name[b] == '>') {
        name.erase(a, (b + 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

In this part of code your are erasing a part of length (b), while you should erase a part of length (b - a)

Try this one:

```
for (int b = a; b < name.length(); b++) {
    if (name[b] == '>') {
        name.erase(a, (b - a + 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

It should works as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another less convoluted and slightly cleaner way that is arguably more readable. It does not deal with nested tags, but you could expand upon it to make it better.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string html = "<HTML> Something <b> slightly less </b> profane here <test>";

    while (html.find("<") != std::string::npos)
    {
        auto startpos = html.find("<");
        auto endpos = html.find(">") + 1;

        if (endpos != std::string::npos)
        {
            html.erase(startpos, endpos - startpos);
        }
    }

    std::cout << html << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

For clarity, `std::string::npos` is returned when the sought after string has no position in the string. So while there are still HTML opening tags in the document. Erase everything between the first opening and first closing bracket you can find. It does not separate from `5 < 2` for example and `<html>`, so there are flaws, but it shows a different approach you can apply as a starting point.

Comment: This removes a lot of uncertainty regarding the state of the indexing or iterators after `.erase()`. It is unclear how fragile an indexed or iterator approach would be given the effect of `.erase()` on the string itself, especially within an indexed `for` loop where the length of the sting is changing. It does however produce the anticipated output (the only question is how many times undefined behavior was invoked underneath)

Comment: The only tweak I could suggest would be `if (endpos != std::string::npos) html.erase(startpos, endpos - startpos);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yep that makes sense, overlooked that. Updated answer to fix now.

Comment: Thanks, you already had my vote, I was just stumbling around trying to find a standards reference for how the string behaves regarding existing indexing when `.erase()` is used. And also the effect of modifying the `for` loop counter thereby within the loop. I still haven't nailed the applicable section/paragraph down, but I'll get there.